# I am getting an error when running this code saying str1 is not defined,when i have already defined it in try block

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I am trying to write a small code block where in i take an input (user can enter any input in words or letters), my code should try to find if it is a positive or negative number or the entered value is a string.

```
try:
    str1=int(input('Enter a number:'))
    print('try block is completed')
except:
    str1=str(str1)
if str1>0:
    print('entered value is positive')
elif str1<0:
    print('entered value is negative')
else:
    print(str1)
```

Comment: Enter a number:twenty
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tryexcept.py", line 3, in <module>
        str1=int(input('Enter a number:'))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'twenty'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tryexcept.py", line 7, in <module>
        str1=str(str1)
    NameError: name 'str1' is not defined

Comment: declare str1 before the try block

Comment: But as per my knowledge , the code first eneters the try block and in case of an exception/traceback/error it goes to except by which time str1 is already defined right ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

in the case fn an exception in the call `int`, the variable `str1` never gets created, because `int` is evaluated (and raises the error) before `str1` gets assigned.

also - in the case of an exception you'll get a TypeError for trying to compare a string with 0, so put all you int-assuming logic inside the `try`, like this:

```py
str1=input('Enter a number:')
try:
    str1=int(str1)
    if str1>0:
        print('entered value is positive')
    elif str1<0:
        print('entered value is negative')
except:
    str1=str(str1)
    print(str1)
```

Comment: This one is more valid, it must the accepted answer.

Comment: i expected this to throw an error as ival is a local variable , but this is running fine , why     
   rawstr=input('Enter a number')
   try:
       ival=int(rawstr)
   except:
       ival=-1
   if ival>0:
       print('Nice work')
   else:
       print('Not a Number')

Comment: No, the try block does *not* establish a scope, and variables created inside a try block *are* available outside the block. The problem here is that the assignment never happens at all, because there is an exception while evaluating its right-hand side.

Comment: @TurePålsson, you're 100% correct. GopiB notice my answer was misleading. check this example out: https://ideone.com/lpEhk9

Comment: A good advice with exception handling is, as few as possible in a try block, especially if you don't specify which exceptions you catch.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the exception is caused in int(input(...)) so the str1 remains undeclared.

```
str1=input('Enter a number:')
try:
    str1=int(str1)
    print('try block is completed')
except:
    str1=str(str1)
if str1>0:
    print('entered value is positive')
elif str1<0:
    print('entered value is negative')
else:
    print(str1)
```

Modify your code like this to handle exception on integer and string

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please mark it as accepted asnwer, with tick mark at the left side. thanks.

Comment: Notice: entering a string will follow with a TypeError for comparing `str` to `int`

Comment: I just modified his code. That exception can be handled in the except block anyways.

Answer (score 0):

On your except branch you have the following call:

```
str1=str(str1)
```

Since you are on your except, and you haven't defined your str1 variable outside the try/except block, your statement will fail when it tries to cast the contentes of the str1 variable (which does not exist outside of the try branch).

A possible implementation to deal with this case would be to set str1 to None or an empty string on your except block. Something like this:

```
try:
    str1 = int(input('Enter a number:'))
    print('try block is completed')
except:
    str1 = None
    # First we check that our variable is not None (caught an exception)
try:
    int_str1 = int(str1)
except:
    int_str1 = None
if int_str1:
    if int_str1 > 0:
        print('entered value is positive')
    elif int_str1 < 0:
        print('entered value is negative')
else:
     print('Could not get integer value of input')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use `str1` in your except clause. If there is an exception during the processing of `input` or `int`, the variable `str1` is never set.
If you add `str1=None` before your `try` statement, I am sure, it won't complain anymore, but you need to change your `except` clause then.
If you're just concerned about the cast to int, you could do:

```
str1= None
try:
    str1=input('Enter a number:')
    val=int(str1)
    print('try block is completed')
except:
    val=None

if val is None:
    print('input is not a valid number')
elif val>0:
    print('entered value is positive')
elif val<0:
    print('entered value is negative')
else:
    print(str1)
```